# Javaで，C言語でのマクロを使用するために

Tags: java, preprocessor

今，C++で書かれたソースをJavaに変換しようとしているのですが，
マクロを展開し，書き換えるのに困っています．
特に，#define , #ifdef/#ifndef　の展開に困っています
どなたかこの変換のやりかたを教えていただけないでしょうか…

Comment: マクロ展開プリプロセッサーの部分はテンプレートエンジンなどを利用して作り込むしかないんじゃないかと思います。

Answer (score 4):

Ｃでのマクロをjavaのコードで１００％置き換えるのは、おそらくムリです。

それで、
１．マクロ展開済みのソースをjavaに変換する。
というのが第一案。
ＧＣＣ の場合 `-E -P` のようなオプション。
Ｖｉｓｕａｌ Ｃ＋＋の場合、 `/EP` のようなオプション
を使用することで展開済みのソースが得られます。
例：
`g++ test.cpp -E -P -o test.cp`

２．Ｃのプリプロセッサをマクロを含んだjavaソースに適用する。
というのが第２案。
プリプロセッサの部分が独立したプログラムになっている場合、
（ＧＣＣの場合は`cpp` がプリプロセッサプログラムです）
ソースコードをプリプロセッサプログラムにかましてやります。
例：
`cpp test.java -o C2Java.java`

拡張子を仮に変更してやれば
`g++ test.java.c -E -P -o Test.java`
のようなことでも可能だと思います。

この場合にはやはりjavaコードへの１００％の適用はできないかもしれないです。

Answer (score 2):

Java 言語には C 言語のマクロと同等のものはありません。

ただ、昔からこういう変換は、`public static final ...` で定義されるような変数で行うことが多いです。

### ■ マクロを使った定数

```c
// C
#define MENU_WIDTH 100
#define PAGE_WIDTH ( MENU_WIDTH + 500 )
```

```java
// Java
private static final int MENU_WIDTH = 100;
private static final int PAGE_WIDTH = MENU_WIDTH + 50;
```

### ■ マクロを使った関数

```c
// C
#define multiply( d1, d2 ) ( d1 * d2 )
```

```java
// Java
private static double multiply(double d1, double d2) { return d1 * d2; }
```

### ■ マクロ定義で分岐: `#define` ~ `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` ~ `#endif`

```c
// C
#define IS_AMIGA500
...
#ifdef IS_AMIGA500
...
#endif
```

#### - コンパイル時に決める

`private static final boolean` 定数に対する `if (...) {...}` 分岐は、コンパイラにより(また実行環境により)最適化されますので、以下の方法がよいでしょう。

```java
// Java
private static final boolean IS_AMIGA500 = true;

...
    if ( IS_AMIGA500) {
        ...
    }
```

#### - 実行時に決める

また、実行時に定数値を Java VM に渡す方法もあります。

```java
// Java
private static final boolean IS_AMIGA500 = "true".equals(System.getProperty("IS_AMIGA500"));

...
    if ( IS_AMIGA500) {
        ...
    }
```

```
$ # Console
$ java -DIS_AMIGA500=true MainClass
```

Answer (score 1):

C++のアプリケーションはDLL化してしまって、JavaからはJNIで呼ぶってのはいかがでしょう？